# Issue in Batch apex

Tags: apex

I am working on one requirement which is related to batch apex.
I have two objects, "Opportunity" and "Rep Goals".
On Opportunity I have a multi select picklist field "Population__c" and has values "MBA" "MCA" and "MSC" and have a field "BCOM__c" on Rep Goals Object.
If I select MBA MCA in "Population__c" field in opportunity then I need to increment the counter to 1 in "BCOM__c" on rep goals object.
I don't know how to work on multi select fields, can anyone helps me out how to achieve it.
My code is below.

```
    public static void calculateOpportunities(BCC_Rep_Goal__c repgoal){

    date startdate = repgoal.Month__c.ToStartOfMonth();
    Integer numberOfDays = Date.daysInMonth(repgoal.Month__c.year(), repgoal.Month__c.month());
    date enddate = Date.newInstance(repgoal.Month__c.year(), repgoal.Month__c.month(), numberOfDays);
    repgoal.Posting_Actual__c = 0;
    for(Opportunity opp: [SELECT Id, OwnerId,Population__c, Name, RecordType.Name, Posting_Date__c FROM Opportunity
                          WHERE Posting_Date__c >= :startdate
                          AND Posting_Date__c <= :enddate
                          AND RecordType.Name = 'JIT Postings'
                          AND OwnerId = :repgoal.BD_Rep__c]){
        repgoal.Posting_Actual__c += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Population__c includes ('MBA', 'MCA')` to compare values in multi-select picklist as follows in the SOQL query:

```
for(Opportunity opp: [SELECT Id, OwnerId,Population__c, Name, RecordType.Name, Posting_Date__c 
                          FROM Opportunity
                          WHERE Posting_Date__c >= :startdate
                          AND Posting_Date__c <= :enddate
                          AND RecordType.Name = 'JIT Postings'
                          AND OwnerId = :repgoal.BD_Rep__c
                          AND Population__c includes ('MBA', 'MCA')]){

            repgoal.Posting_Actual__c += 1;
    }
```

For more information, refer [Querying Multi-Select Picklists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm)

Comment: Hello Santanu,thanks a lot for your time and replying me,actually I just mentioned "MBA" and "MCA" for example, I have so many values like that and I need to update different fields based on values of multiselect picklist, can you help me out in this issue.

Comment: You can prepare a list and use like `includes:listOfValues` and later in the for loop you could take required action